# Time Complexity of Collectors.Counting (java)

Tags: java, arraylist, time-complexity

I was doing a homework assignment in programming class and they assignment was to take arraylist a, remove all words from a that are in arraylist b, and return the top 10 used words and their frequencies. So I wrote this:

```java
System.out.println(FrozenNorth.stream()
    .filter(i -> !UselessWords.contains(i))
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        x -> x, 
        Collectors.counting()
    ))
    .entrySet().stream()
    .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue(Comparator.reverseOrder()))
    .limit(10)
    .collect(Collectors.toList())
    .toString()
);
```

FrozenNorth is a and UselessWords is b.
I was just curious, what is the overall time complexity of this? Asking because the implementation we were given instructions for is O(nlogn) so I was wondering if I should just use those instructions instead

Comment: The most expensive thing here is the filter: `contains` on an `ArrayList` is `O(UselessWords.size())`, `FrozenNorth.size()` times, so `O(UW.size() * FN.size())`.

Comment: Two remarks: In java, variable names should always start with a lowercase letter. --- I would suggest to split this one-liner of code into multiple lines to improve readability.

Comment: Please provide full code and please make it readable.